# Reversed sorting in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

How i can sort entites from the end of table? I usualy used reversed comparator.
I try this,but is not work in spring data jpa:

```
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Terapija> top10TerapijePacijenta(String jmbg){
   List<Terapija> ter= terapijaRepository.findByJmbgPacijeta(jmbg);
   Comparator<Terapija> comp = comp.reversed();

  return  ter.sort(comp);
```

Comment: `terapijaRepository.findByJmbgPacijetaOrderByIdDesc`

Comment: that return me i think first result from the table

Comment: It should not return the first element only. To get first element you need findFirst...

Comment: @J.P  `terapijaRepository.findByJmbgPacijetaOrderByIdAsc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define new method in the Repository that will specify the ordering. Assuming you want the first created rows on the top, order the result by ID in ascending order

```
List<Terapija> terapijaRepository.findByJmbgPacijetaOrderByIdAsc();
```